# Each current_user Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have website with users posts. I want add to their profiles their posts and all posts on the main page.
So, in the controller and the main page, I set up displaying all posts.
But how I can set this in users profiles in '/edit' (their posts?)

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end
```

main_page

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

By current_user?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Can you explain in more detail what your desired outcome is, and what you have tried?  When you reference something on an `/edit` path, do you mean `/users/:id/edit` or `/posts/:id/edit` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to display posts by user according to `current_user` (assuming `current_user` is an Active Record object you would need to do this:

No Relation:

> In the controller:

`@posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)`

> In the view:

`<% @posts.each do |post| %>
...
<% end %>`

Active Record Relation:

> In the controller:

`@posts = current_user.posts`

> In the view:

`<% @posts.each do |post| %>
...
<% end %>`

Comment: But I want display in the main page all posts and in user profil his posts so how Can I set this in controller?

Comment: @karoltyk The code is literally above in the answer. What is `current_user`? Is it an active record object? Or is it a session with an id in it?

Answer (score 0):

To display all posts..use the already defined index method.

```
def index
   @posts = Post.all
end
```

To display posts corresponding to a particular user, defined a method named user_posts in the controller

```
def user_posts
   @posts = current_user.posts   // if relation between user and posts is being defined as association
   @posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user.id) // if relation between user and posts is not defined via association
 end
```

User the corresponding instance(@posts) in the view to iterate over and show on the view page.

Comment: i get this: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It means that the object on which you are iterating does not contain a value..inspect instance variable and check if there are any posts included in @posts.